# failed to use TLS with Couchbase Python SDK 3.0.x

Tags: python, couchbase

I'm trying to use Couchbase Python SDK 3.0.x to connect to a cluster. I followed the document (https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/3.0/howtos/managing-connections.html#ssl) to create the certificate file and used it with the following code:

```
cluster = Cluster("couchbase://10.82.xxx.xxx:18091", ClusterOptions(PasswordAuthenticator(DEST_USR, DEST_PW, cert_path="./cert.crt")))
```

However when I run it it gives the following:

```
$ python3 mycode.py 
creating couchbase instance seriesMgmt@10.82.xxx.xxx:18091
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scheduleCache.py", line 29, in <module>
    cluster = Cluster("couchbase://"+DEST_CB_IP, ClusterOptions(PasswordAuthenticator(DEST_USR, DEST_PW, cert_path="./cert.crt")))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/couchbase/cluster.py", line 492, in __init__
    super(Cluster, self).__init__(connection_string=str(self.connstr), _conntype=_LCB.LCB_TYPE_CLUSTER, **self._clusteropts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/couchbase_core/client.py", line 141, in __init__
    super(Client, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
couchbase.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: <Bad/insufficient arguments provided, inner_cause='certpath' is an invalid keyword argument for this function, C Source=(src/bucket.c,1047)>
```

I believe it's not about the correctness of my cert file yet - somehow the SDK just doesn't want to take the parameter `cert_path`. Tried to remove the parameter name and it doesn't help:

```
cluster = Cluster("couchbase://10.82.xxx.xxx:18091", ClusterOptions(PasswordAuthenticator(DEST_USR, DEST_PW, "./cert.crt")))
```

BTW I can login `https://10.82.xxx.xxx:18091` via browser without any problem.

Comment: Hi Matthew, did you find the problem there ? i'm facing the same issue :/

Comment: @ShalomBalulu unfortunately no. so for the task I went to use Java client instead.